# Drupal install on different hosting

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, hosting

I installed my drupal page on a hosting and i have a domain but this domain is hosted by an another company. Is there a small fix to connect the host and domain ?

Inside drupal settings.php by default is this, yes i already have the user sql everything but dont know how to connect the domain and hosting... maybe i need to add the Ip of the hosting ? but where?  :

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
'driver' => 'mysql',
'database' => 'databasename',
'username' => 'username',
'password' => 'password',
'host' => 'localhost',
'prefix' => 'main_',
'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci', );
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you set up a reverse proxy on the domain?  reverse proxy www.domain.com --> www.drupalhost.com/drupal

Answer (score 0):

Connecting a domain and hosting has nothing to do with Drupal. That bit of script in the settings is only telling Drupal where the MySQL server is. localhost meaning that the MySQL server is on the same server as that file (the same server as Drupal).

You need to login to your domain registrar and enter the nameservers for your host.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way is to change your current DNS settings for your domain and point them to the server where your drupal website is hosted.

another possibility is to go to your domain registry and change the authoritative NS hosts for your domain to the ones provided by your host, so you can manage your DNS settings via your webhost and connect your domain to your server.

your webhost support should help you regarding this if you're still not sure how to do it.